Python crashed. Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
I am using Python to convert CSV files to xlsx files. It works well when I am dealing with smaller files, but when I am dealing with larger files, it will prompt "1073741819 (0xC000000 5)"
I have tried different versions of Python and different libraries, but all have the same results. I tried using a VM virtual machine to create a new system to run the code, but the problem persisted.
At the same time, I also noticed a Python crash warning in the system log. Every time I receive "1073741819 (0xC000000 5)", I can see an error message in the system log
Wrong application name: python.exe，version: 3.12.3150.1013，time stamp: 0x66154bab
Wrong module name: python312.dll，version: 3.12.3150.1013，time stamp: 0x66154b63
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Error offset: 0x0000000000037886
Error process ID: 0x894
Wrong application startup time: 0x01daa7b22147afbc
Wrong application path: C:\Users\Lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe
Wrong module path: C:\Users\Lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python312.dll
Report ID: 5cadb8e6-9e14-441f-a060-138a0723a53f
Error Package Full Name: 
Error package relative to application ID:: 


It's strange that I'm running the same code on my laptop, it works well, and there's no problem with the large files, so I'm starting to suspect that my device might be malfunctioning, and I'm confused. I'm using I9-13900K and DDR5. I don't know if anyone here can help me,
This is my code
import csv
from openpyxl import Workbook

def csv_to_xlsx(csv_file, xlsx_file):

    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    ws.title = "Sheet1"

    with open(csv_file, 'r', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        ws.append(next(reader)) 

        for row in reader:
            ws.append(row)
    wb.save(xlsx_file)
csv_file_path = 'F:\\1.csv'  
xlsx_file_path = 'F:\\data.xlsx'  
csv_to_xlsx(csv_file_path, xlsx_file_path)



Maybe the line that says "wrong application name" and "pythn.exe" is a hint... I also see a "pythonxe" elsewhere in the message. Did you happen to misspell "python.exe" two different ways somewhere?

Sorry for using translation, I have updated it.

C0000005 is a CPU access violation -- a process trying to access an invalid address.  You might try to run a memory test.
